# Is Kerabond T with additive okay for under Ditra Heat?

Tags: tile, mortar, radiant-heating, floorheating, porcelain

I'm looking to install porcelain tile over Ditra heat mat in our kitchen. From what I read you need to use a modified thinset for under the ditra mat(over plywood subfloor), and unmodified for over the ditra and under the porcelain tiles. I went to the local Lowe's and wasn't sure what to buy.

I'm not entirely sure what is what. I ended up buying Kerabond T - Medium-Bed and Thinset Tile Mortar and a jug of Keralastic.

Would this work if I added the Keralastic for under the ditra and don't add it for on top of ditra?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

should be fine, ditra mats require modified mortar under the mats when going over wood subfloor with a 1/4 x 1/4 inch trowel, unmodified on top. schluter is making there own mortar now btw, it allows you to use modified thru out.